# Overflow saved RIP register value with short address

Tags: null, gdb, buffer-overflow, strcpy, eip

I'm trying to do buffer overflow where I need to rewrite the saved RIP register value with an address.

The address is short (8 bytes), for example, 0x0000000012345678. The RIP register is 16 bytes, but if I input 0's, it terminates the string (because the buffer is being overflowed with `strcpy`). How do I get around rewriting with a short address without terminating the string?

I'm looking at the value by setting a break point at main in gdb, and stepping through until it copies the string, then looking at the saved RIP value with the `info frame` command.

This seems like it would be a common problem, but I guess I'm not googling properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The RIP register is 16 bytes,

There are no current processors with 128 bit addresses; the above statement is false.

> How do I get around rewriting with a short address without terminating the string?

Use something other than `strcpy` to perform the overflow.

> I'm not allowed to change the code

In that case, your task of "overflow with short address via `strcpy`" becomes impossible.

However, you may still achieve the end result by first overflowing the return address with a trampoline that points to e.g. `memcpy` (you didn't say what OS you are using, but on e.g. Linux `memcpy` will usually have a "long" address), and then having `memcpy` overflow the return address a second time (`memcpy` will not stop on `NUL` character).

This technique is called [return to libc attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-to-libc_attack).

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the code though, and I know it's possible because somebody else I know doing this CTF figured it out.  The RIP register shows as 12 bytes long, but I figured there were just 4 zero bytes that weren't being shown. Either way I need to overflow it with an 8 byte address.